# proving that a function from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$ is surjective

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ be a continuous function such that $|f(x) - x| < 2017 \space$ $\forall$ $x\in \Bbb R^2$.
prove that $f$ is surjective.

please help me prove this statement.
thank you very much.

Comment: are you sure you want this tagged as algebraic topology?

Comment: It might be related to the fixed point theorem..

Comment: I can prove that $0\in Im(f)$ using the fixed point theorem for x-f(x)

Comment: SZN yes, I think it's related to retracts

Comment: ok, what after I proved $0 \in Im(f)$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define $g:B(0,2017)\rightarrow B(0,2017)$ by $g(y)=y-f(y)$. Obviously $g$ is continuous and it's image is $B(0,2017)$. By Brouwer's fixed point theorem [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem) there exists $y_0\in B(0,2017)$ so that $g(y_0)=y_0$ in particular it follows that $f(y_0)=0$.

We are going to modify this argument a little bit and we will get that $f$ is onto

Let $x$ be any element in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and consider $g(y)=y+x-f(y+x)$ again, $g:B(0,2017)\rightarrow B(0,2017)$ and again there exists $y_0$ so that $g(y_0)=y_0+x-f(y_0+x)=y_0$ in particular $f(y_0+x)=x$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^ 2$

Comment: Which fixed-point theorem are you using? And why is the image $B(0,2017)$?

Comment: I think it should be Brower fix pint theorme not the classical one +1

Comment: Brouwer's and because $|f(y)-y|<2017$

Comment: Ok see the edit now. He put there. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: yes sorry I'm not aware to other famous fixed point theorems...

Comment: Brouwer's fixed-point theorem seems to require a closed ball. Isn't this an issue in this case?

Comment: Nope, just think of $B(0,2017)$ as the closed ball (you are right that the image is in fact a subset of the open ball but this doesn't matter..)

Comment: thanks for the solution, can you please help me disprove it if the function $f$ is not continuous?

Answer (score 5):

If $\|x\|\to\infty$ then clearly $\|f(x)\|\to\infty$. This means that after a $1$-point compactification of $R^2$, you can continuously extent $f$ to a function $S^2\to S^2$ via $f(\infty)=\infty$. Further, $f: S^2\to S^2$ is homotopic to the identity map, because the homotopy $(x,t)\mapsto x+t(f(x)-x)$ can be continuously extended to a pointed homotopy of the sphere via $(\infty,t)\mapsto\infty$. Hence the degree of $f$ is $1$ and $f$ is surjective.